# Best way to communicate data wirelessly with specific conditions

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery, waves

So I need two modules to give each other data with the following conditions:

- They are relatively short range. They need to be near each other to transmit the data, say around 5 cm.
- They are relatively small.
- Battery powered, preferably ready to transmit the moment its turned on with a switch.
- The data they receive should be sent via bluetooth to another device (There is a reason I can't use bluetooth directly)

Comment: What bandwidth is required?  Any constraints on cost size or power?

Comment: Cost is irrelevant for now. Bandwidth also. Its just some kb of data. Power is what a small battery can provide, like a clock one

Comment: NFC is designed for this.

Comment: How about Thread or Zigbee.